# installing the ogre3d SDK for windows

Tags: sdk, ogre3d

So I need help installing the SDK. I'm using windows vista and i downloaded the sdk (OGRE 1.8.0 SDK for MinGW)

i'm following these rules:

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+the+Ogre+SDK

I got to the part where i unpacked the files in a folder called "java"

and the full path is:

**C:\Users\Andy Chan\Desktop\java\OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-0**

This next part is the part that I'm stuck in. If I open command line (I have like no knowledge of the command prompt) it will say:

C:\users\Andy Chan>
[image]
I  I typed in setx OGRE_HOME + build path (see image)

but it doesn't seem to work. Also, my cmd is different from the one in the tutorial so I'm really lost. I'm a total newbie when it comes to command prompts...

Can anyone give me like, an easy step by step process of how to set the environment variable OGRE_HOME to point to that path?

I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your path has a whitespace, use double quotes on it:

```
setx OGRE_HOME "c:\Users\Andy Chan\Desktop\java\OgreSDK_MinGW_v1-8-0"
```

If you do not use whitespace, the command prompt will split the path in multiple arguments and this confuses the setx command.